# joomla broken and can't figure it out

Tags: joomla

Transfering a Joomla site to a new server, not really experienced.

Apache is set up, MySQL is live and the DB was imported, the user/pass/path and config were updated accordingly.

The DB connected and gave me this wierd error. I did some research and someone suggested to drop the jos_ table and recreate it by doing the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_session` (
`username` varchar(150) default '',
`time` varchar(14) default '',
`session_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
`guest` tinyint(4) default '1',
`userid` int(11) default '0',
`usertype` varchar(50) default '',
`gid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`client_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`data` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`(64)),
KEY `whosonline` (`guest`,`usertype`),
KEY `userid` (`userid`),
KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So, now that that was done, I get the following:

404 - Component not found
You may not be able to visit this page because of:

an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
a mistyped address
you have no access to this page
The requested resource was not found.
An error has occurred while processing your request.
Please try one of the following pages:

Home Page

When I try to access the homepage (index.php) it does the same thing....

What the heck did I do and how do I fix this?

Any help is most appreciated -

ORIGINAL ERROR (Just restored again):

jtablesession::Store Failed
DB function failed with error number 1146
Table 'plumblev_joom347.jos_session' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_session` ( `session_id`,`time`,`username`,`gid`,`guest`,`client_id` ) VALUES ( '9890e7d1fa915e26d17121dd4eed8004','1369667714','','0','1','0' )

Comment: What was the initial error you got before you changed the stuff in the database?

Comment: @Bakual - I just restored it again. 

jtablesession::Store Failed
DB function failed with error number 1146
Table 'plumblev_joom347.jos_session' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_session` ( `session_id`,`time`,`username`,`gid`,`guest`,`client_id` ) VALUES ( '9890e7d1fa915e26d17121dd4eed8004','1369667714','','0','1','0' )

Comment: Does the database have the name `plumblev_joom347`? If not, you need to adjust this in your configuration.php file. If yes, does a table with the name `jos_session` exist? If not, does one exists with a different prefix (jos_)? If yes, you need to adjust the prefix in your configuration.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving shouldn't be a problem as long as you adjust the configuration.php file accordingly, especially the paths.
I would just try and move the tables from the old server again to the new one, overwriting the new tables. That is as long as you use the same Joomla version on both servers.

Comment: Dumb question... I just FTP'd over the folder and the db. I'll reload it again but will probably get the same problem. Is this how to transfer a joomla! site?

Comment: It should work, if you edit the configuration.php to reflect the new folder paths and the new database connection settings.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid to move a Joomla! site manually, if you're not familiar with that. There are a lot of settings, which have to be adjusted.

Better use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) together with [Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html) for that. It even allows you to change the database prefix during transfer.

Comment: it's already done and I have to do my best... any suggestions other than 'don't do it' ?

Comment: I recommend to re-do it as described above. It takes only a couple of minutes. The problem you have can be caused by many things, but your question does not give the right hints. With Akeeba, you get a clean re-install. From there (*before* you change anything after installation) its worth trying do get closer to the root problem.

Comment: @nibra, there are not at all that many setting to be changed. Only database settings (2 lines min) then tmp and logs folder locations

Comment: I wanted to ensure a *clean* install. If you copy an installation manually, a) you don't have a pre-installation check, and b) you have to adapt the configuration manually, which is prone to typos.

Answer (score -1):

Can you access the administrator? If so, make sure you have a default page set and also that it is set to public.